# Minimum browser support to run an Angular 5 app with Typescript 2.6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, typescript2.6

I am looking for the minimum chrome, firefox and safari version to execute a web application build with Angular 5 and Typescript 2.6. The Angular Readme.md doesn't have any information about it. Anyone can help me? Or there is an application to get that information? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, angular is not more then Javascript. Using Typescript does not influence support as it gets built into Javascript as part of the angular build process.

Support to older browsers depends on the [Polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) you use when building the project.  Having a lot of pollyfills will make your app files bigger in size and less performant. The latest angular (11 as of today) dropped support for older browsers as it no longer loads the polyfills for older browsers. The current supported Browsers can be found in [Angular's page](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support).

[Angular 5 supporte browsers](https://v5.angular.io/guide/browser-support) can also be found there, here is a copy of what they have:

| Browser | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome | latest |
| Firefox | latest |
| Edge | 2 most recent major versions |
| IE | 11, 10, 9 |
| IE Mobile | 11 |
| Safari | 2 most recent major versions |
| iOS | 2 most recent major versions |
| Android | Nougat (7.0), Marshmallow (6.0), Lollipop (5.0, 5.1), KitKat (4.4) |